# Failed to parse: filter: mongoDB error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to query the data from a collection with a date range field , my document has regex search implemented,

my query is as follows,

```
 db.getCollection('_event').find([{"name":{"$regex":"2017","$options":"i"}},{},{"date.start:{$gte":"2017-03-07T18:30:00.000Z"},{"date.end:{$lt":"2017-11-16T18:30:00.000Z"}])
```

and mongo throws an error

> Error: error: {   "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),     "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" :
>   "Failed to parse: filter: [ { name: { $regex: \"2017\", $options:
>   \"i\" } }, {}, { date.start:{$gte: \"2017-03-07T18:30:00.000Z\" }, {
>   date.end:{$lt: \"2017-11-16T18:30:00.000Z\" } ]. 'filter' field must
>   be of BSON type Object.",     "code" : 9 }

any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the `find` method must be a JSON/BSON document, not a list.  Try

```
db.getCollection('_event').find({
       "name":{"$regex":"2017","$options":"i"},
       "date.start":{"$gte":"2017-03-07T18:30:00.000Z"},
       "date.end":{"$lt":"2017-11-16T18:30:00.000Z"}
})
```